# If you root your phone should you do OTA update?

Tags: rooting

I am rooting my xiaomi phone.

I am using instruction here

http://en.miui.com/thread-190889-1-1.html

The truth is I actually prefer to wait till I have an update. Device enscryption for xiaomi doesn't work yet. Some said it will work for miui 7.1

Well, I go ahead and root it anyway.

WHat about if latter miui 7.1 is available?

Should I just do OTA?

Comment: OTA on a Lollipop device would and should fail if the device is rooted. Rooting compromises the integrity of system partition.

Comment: So what should I do then if I want to upgrade my miui?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you update your rooted phone you will lose your root access and will need to root your phone again which could be a problem because previous method of rooting may not be working on new version. You will need to wait until the same rooting method you used earlier releases a compatible update or you might need to find a compatible method.

Answer (score 0):

I read the instructions and it seems safe. You could run into problems if you OTA while having a custom recovery like TWRP or CWM. However, that method does not seem to require you to change your recovery. Keep in mind that after you apply the OTA there's a good chance that the root will be lost, and you might not be able to re-gain it until a new method is found for the new ROM version.

Good luck!